# Mac OS X: Installed X11 from XQuartz - now apps using X11 don't work

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, xorg, gimp

I recently installed [X11-2.5.3 from macosforge.org](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki), and now I can't open app's that use X11, such as the Gimp. When I try to open that applictaion, the following happens:

1. The Gimp icon appears in the dock
2. The X11.app icon appears in the dock
3. Nothing else happens - Gimp is unresponsive.

I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.4. And a funny thing (which might be related to the problem), if I open the X11.app manually, it identifies itself as version 2.3.5, which is the version from apple, not the one I installed.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to open XQuartz.app, not X11.app from /Applications/Utilities. Then it all works!